# Can recvfrom function from Socket extract the sender IP address?

Tags: c, sockets

We know the Recvfrom function has following synopses

```
    SYNOPSIS
#include <sys/socket.h>
int recvfrom(int s, void *buf, size_t len, int flags, struct sockaddr *from, socklen_t *fromlen);
```

The from has the struct of sockaddr.

```
struct sockaddr {
                __uint8_t   sa_len;     // total length
                sa_family_t sa_family;  // [XSI] address family 
                char        sa_data[14];    // [XSI] addr value (actually larger)
            };
```

But sockaddr doesn't seem to able to hold IP address.

Shouldn't recvfrom be using struct socaddr_in * from  because

```
        struct sockaddr_in {
            __uint8_t   sin_len;
            sa_family_t sin_family;
            in_port_t   sin_port;
            struct  in_addr sin_addr;
            char        sin_zero[8];
        };
```

And sin_addr will give the IP address.  Is that a valid assumption?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 11):

The `from` parameter is defined as `sockaddr*` for historic reasons, to support legacy code that predates IPv6. `sock_addr` is fairly agnostic, but it also is not large enough to handle newer socket types.  Any socket function that has a `sockaddr*` parameter actually expects whatever `sockaddr`-based struct is appropriate for the type of socket that is being used.

If you read from an IPv4 socket, it expects a `sockaddr_in*`, eg:

```
struct sockaddr_in from;
socklen_t len = sizeof(from);
recvfrom(s, ..., (struct sockaddr*)&from, &len); 
// use from.sin_addr and from.sin_port as needed...
```

If you read from an IPv6 socket, it expects a `sockaddr_in6*` instead, eg:

```
struct sockaddr_in6 from;
socklen_t len = sizeof(from);
recvfrom(s, ..., (struct sockaddr*)&from, &len); 
// use from.sin6_addr and from.sin6_port as needed...
```

If you want to write code that supports multiple protocols, use `sockaddr_storage` and type-cast as needed, eg:

```
struct sockaddr_storage from;
socklen_t len = sizeof(from);
recvfrom(s, ..., (struct sockaddr*)&from, &len); 
switch (from.ss_family)
{
    case AF_INET:
        // use ((struct sockaddr_in*)&from) as needed...
        break;
    case AF_INET6:
        // use ((struct sockaddr_in6*)&from) as needed...
        break;
    ...
}
```

The same applies to other `sockaddr`-based functions, including `connect()`, `bind()`, `accept()` and `sendto()`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use a `sockaddr_storage` structure, which is guaranteed to be at least as large as any of the `sockaddr_<protocol>` types supported by the OS.

Comment: recvfrom() is defined as `ssize_t recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags, struct sockaddr *src_addr, socklen_t *addrlen);` in https://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom. The last parameter is a pointer to a socklen_t struct, I don't think you can use sizeof() directly for that.

Comment: @Jaakko I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed as follows:

```
struct scokaddr_in A;
char buf[200];
int len;
recvfrom(fd, buf, 200, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&A, &len);
//from ip-address is stored in A.sin_addr...
```

Comment: Well, I already listed struct sockaddr {
                __uint8_t   sa_len;     // total length
                sa_family_t sa_family;  // [XSI] address family 
                char        sa_data[14];    // [XSI] addr value (actually larger)
            };   sockaddr doesn't have a sin_addr field.

Comment: This example will only work for IPv4, but not for IPv6, or any other socket type for that matter (sockets are not limited to just IP protocols). Also, you have to initialize `len` before calling `recvfrom` so it knows how large `A` is. `recvfrom` will fail if `A` is too small to receive the source address.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to save the IP address as a string, you could use the `inet_ntop()` function. [Beej's guide](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/#inet_ntopman) provides some usefull info about how to use it, with IP-version agnostic examples.